# How to split ics calendar events in Powershell

Tags: arrays, regex, string, powershell, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to write a script to merge two Google calendar ics files and remove duplicate events. Using Powershell I tried the following

```
$cal1 = get-content ".\googlecalendar.ics"
$calarr = $cal1 -replace ("BEGIN.VEVENT","###EVENTDELIM###`r`nBEGIN.VEVENT") -split ("###EVENTDELIM###")
$calarr[4]
```

$calarr[4] produces METHOD:PUBLISH

However, this produces an array of the line by line strings of the file. I am expecting each object in the array to be a multi-line string.

I also tried another solution using regex like this.

```
$cal1 = get-content ".\googlecalendar.ics"
$calarr = ([Regex]'BEGIN:VEVENT([\s\S]*?)END:VEVENT').Matches($cal1).Value
$calarr[4]
```

$calarr[4] produces BEGIN:VEVENT DTSTART:20090929T220000Z DTEND:20090929T230000Z DTSTAMP:20180326T211259Z UID:dfjkadfawerjj14543@google.com CREATED:20090929T204053Z DESCRIPTION: LAST-MODIFIED:20091014T094735Z LOCATION: SEQUENCE:0 STATUS:CONFIRMED SUMMARY:intv TRANSP:OPA
QUE END:VEVENT

But that solution garbles up the individual line endings. Each key and value pair should be on their own line.

What is the proper way to do sub-string selections in Powershell then to cast them into an array while both preserving non-printing characters and also the sub-string headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I forgot that Powershell does weird things to text files with get-content. My regex solution started preserving line endings when I forced PS to read the text file contents using the following

```
[string]$cal1 = get-content ".\googlecalendar.ics" -Raw
```

I forgot that Powershell naturally turns a text file into an array of lines.

Answer (score 0):

> However, this produces an array of the line by line strings of the file. I am expecting each object in the array to be a multi-line string.

Send your array to `Out-String` to get a multi-line string.